# Obtener valor de un suscribe de forma inmediata en angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

sigo teniendo problemas con los suscribe de angular... No acabo de entenderlos...

Tengo un componente que una vez obtiene los parametros necesarios emite un evento a otro servicio para que ejecute una serie de funciones. El problema es que para que esas funciones funcionen, antes tengo que hacer una llamada a la API para obtener unos valores.

Componente 1:

```
loadGraphData(parameters?: IMetabaseGraphParameters) {
    this.loaded$.next(false);
    this.service.loadAnalitycs(parameters).subscribe(data => {
      this.service.graphUrls$.next(data);
      this.loaded$.next(true);
    });
```

Servicio:

```
 loadAnalitycs(parameters: IMetabaseGraphParameters = {}): Observable<IMetabaseURL[]> {

/* Aqui necesito tener los valores que me devuelve la api para 
  usarlos en las funciones que vienen a continuacion */

        this.startDate = parameters.startDate;
        this.endDate = parameters.endDate;
    
        if (parameters.ratio === AnalyticsRatio.project) {
          if (parameters.detail === AnalyticsDetail.nota) {
            return this.loadByWorkshopNote(parameters.value);
          } else {
            return this.loadByWork(parameters.value);
          }
        } else {
          if (parameters.detail === AnalyticsDetail.section) {
            return this.loadByFacilitySection();
          } else {
            return this.loadByFacilityResource()
          }
        }
      }
```

Gracias por ayuda!

Comment: La data de loadAnalitycs la queres obtener en donde dice Aqui necesito tener los valores... ?

Comment: agrega el metodo al ngOnInit(){} y cuando cargue el componente hara el llamado, [ciclo de vida un componente](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) <= aca tienes la documentacion por que la quieres ver.

Comment: @Franco donde he puesto los comentarios es donde quiero obtener los valores de la api

Comment: @AndresAbadia Si lo cargo en el onInit() se ejecutara antes que la funcion loadAnalitycs? Ten en cuenta que es el componente el que llama a esa funcion del servicio....

Comment: @Carlos y has probrado usar [concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat) de Rxjs, que te ayuda a llamar Observables de manera ordenada?

Comment: Pues no veo que te estes suscribiendo a this.service.graphUrls$ que es donde viene la data cuando haces el llamado del componente 1.

Comment: Le estas pasando data pero ajam, donde te suscribes?

Answer (score 0):

Si nunca te subscribes a un observable nunca obtendras el flujo de datos del mismo.

```
 loadAnalitycs(parameters: IMetabaseGraphParameters = {}): Observable<IMetabaseURL[]> {

/* Aqui necesito tener los valores que me devuelve la api para 
  usarlos en las funciones que vienen a continuacion */
        this.service.graphUrls$.subscribe(data => {
            console.log('llego la data', data)
        }

        this.startDate = parameters.startDate;
        this.endDate = parameters.endDate;
    
        if (parameters.ratio === AnalyticsRatio.project) {
          if (parameters.detail === AnalyticsDetail.nota) {
            return this.loadByWorkshopNote(parameters.value);
          } else {
            return this.loadByWork(parameters.value);
          }
        } else {
          if (parameters.detail === AnalyticsDetail.section) {
            return this.loadByFacilitySection();
          } else {
            return this.loadByFacilityResource()
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Realmente necesito recuperar otros datos llamando a una api, pero poniendolo en la linea donde lo has puesto tu, cuando llega al primer return todavia no ha obtenido los datos...

Comment: No te entiendo, como que necesitas recuperar otros datos??